# Create frequency polygon from overlapping features in another polygon

Tags: qgis, polygon, spatial-join, overlapping-features, frequency

Mac 10.9.5; QGIS 2.8.4-Wien; history and unioned data, in GDA94, zone 55 [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/o81rbho2iqjfzng/polygon_data.zip?dl=0).

I have a polygon of fire history with a number of overlapping features. I want to create a new polygon for fire frequency, where each feature has a count of the overlapping features in the history polygon.

The attached data is a small subset of my full data set, so I need a method that will be manageable with a large data set.

I unioned the history polygon to itself to get the individual features that should contain the frequencies. I previously followed Donovan Cameron's method in ArcGIS (http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=987&t=282764) with success. However, there is no 'summarize' option in QGIS, so I get stuck at point #6 in that method. I no longer have access to ArcGIS, so I am looking for a QGIS solution.

Here are some other things I've tried:

- In another ArcGIS method (gis.stackexchange.com/questions/51929/how-to-count-and-rasterize-polygon-overlaps-in-arcgis-desktop), I get stuck at the 'dissolve' step (step 2) because there is no option to count in the dissolve tool for QGIS.
- In the spaghetti and meatball (blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2012/11/13/spaghetti_and_meatballs/) method, I substituted 'Feature to polygon' with union, and used Vector>Geometry tools>Polygon centroids (instead of the suggested Feature to point tool). At the intersect step I get an empty polygon so I tried to use the spatial join then join steps. This produced a range of the counts I was expecting (0-4) but not all of the original unioned polygon features were retained and the spatial configuration of counts were incorrect.
- Finally, I've tried raster solutions (e.g. [Creating a raster surface of overlaps from vector polygon shapefiles?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6167/creating-a-raster-surface-of-overlaps-from-vector-polygon-shapefiles)), but I can't work out how to split my polygon features into separate polygons (multipart to single part returns an indentical polygon).

Answer (score 2):

I think you could use the **Join attributes by location** tool which allows you to extract some statistical data from two layers such as sum of values, feature count etc. This can be accessed from:

*Processing Toolbox > QGIS geoalgorithms, Vector general tools > Join attributes by location*

[image: Join attributes by location interface]

Note that the we are taking the **summary of intersecting features**. You can choose to keep the `sum`, `mean` etc parameters or remove them entirely. The output will always contain a `count` field which counts the number of intersecting features. Here was the result:

[image: Result]

Comment: I did try that too; the counts should be in the range 0-8, not what is returned using join attributes by location. I had a chance to test this on ArcGIS yesterday and realised that the union polygon (attached), generated in QGIS is not correct either. So I need to sort that out before I make further progress with summarising frequencies. I'm using the Arc solution for now, but would still like a QGIS method for future use.

Comment: @asmith - Interesting, I wonder where the **Union** function went wrong. Atleast you have more _correct_ results from Arc as this method for QGIS has worked for me in the past :)

Answer (score 0):

**Unfortunately, my tests show that this is a very slow method. If you have any ideas how to optimize the processing, I would be glad to read your comments. It takes 2 minutes and 24 seconds to process 70 heavily overlapping circles like that:**

[image]

**My current analysis of this task shows that using the `Union` tool may gives no result at all (the process ends with an error due to too many overlapping objects).**

Input polygons: [image]  Final result: [image]

Here's how it currently works (there's a standard QGIS tool for each step):

1. Convert the input polygons into lines. [Polygons to lines](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#qgispolygonstolines)
2. Split the input polygons with lines.  [Split with lines](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoroverlay.html#qgissplitwithlines)
3. Calculate the centroids of the polygons. [Point on Surface](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#qgispointonsurface)
4. Remove duplicate geometries.  [Delete duplicate geometries](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#qgisdeleteduplicategeometries)
5. Count the points in the polygons. [Count points in polygon](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoranalysis.html#qgiscountpointsinpolygon)

[image: Processing Steps]  < == <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Left Mouse Click</kbd>  to watch

I made a custom processing tool for this task (copy the code below and save it as a *.model3 file):

[image: QGIS Custom Model]

```
<!DOCTYPE model>
<Option type="Map">
  <Option name="children" type="Map">
    <Option name="native:countpointsinpolygon_1" type="Map">
      <Option name="active" type="bool" value="true"/>
      <Option name="alg_config"/>
      <Option name="alg_id" type="QString" value="native:countpointsinpolygon"/>
      <Option name="color" type="QString" value=""/>
      <Option name="comment" type="Map">
        <Option name="color" type="QString" value=""/>
        <Option name="component_description" type="QString" value=""/>
        <Option name="component_height" type="double" value="60"/>
        <Option name="component_pos_x" type="double" value="1520"/>
        <Option name="component_pos_y" type="double" value="680"/>
        <Option name="component_width" type="double" value="100"/>
        <Option name="outputs_collapsed" type="bool" value="true"/>
        <Option name="parameters_collapsed" type="bool" value="true"/>
      </Option>
      <Option name="component_description" type="QString" value="Count points in polygon"/>
      <Option name="component_height" type="double" value="30.000000000000004"/>
      <Option name="component_pos_x" type="double" value="730"/>
      <Option name="component_pos_y" type="double" value="465"/>
      <Option name="component_width" type="double" value="200"/>
      <Option name="dependencies"/>
      <Option name="id" type="QString" value="native:countpointsinpolygon_1"/>
      <Option name="outputs"/>
      <Option name="outputs_collapsed" type="bool" value="true"/>
      <Option name="parameters_collapsed" type="bool" value="true"/>
      <Option name="params" type="Map">
        <Option name="CLASSFIELD" type="List">
          <Option type="Map">
            <Option name="source" type="int" value="2"/>
            <Option name="static_value" type="QString" value=""/>
          </Option>
        </Option>
        <Option name="FIELD" type="List">
          <Option type="Map">
            <Option name="source" type="int" value="2"/>
            <Option name="static_value" type="QString" value="NUMPOINTS"/>
          </Option>
        </Option>
        <Option name="POINTS" type="List">
          <Option type="Map">
            <Option name="child_id" type="QString" value="native:pointonsurface_1"/>
            <Option name="output_name" type="QString" value="OUTPUT"/>
            <Option name="source" type="int" value="1"/>
          </Option>
        </Option>
        <Option name="POLYGONS" type="List">
          <Option type="Map">
            <Option name="child_id" type="QString" value="native:deleteduplicategeometries_1"/>
            <Option name="output_name" type="QString" value="OUTPUT"/>
            <Option name="source" type="int" value="1"/>
          </Option>
        </Option>
        <Option name="WEIGHT" type="List">
          <Option type="Map">
            <Option name="source" type="int" value="2"/>
            <Option name="static_value" type="QString" value=""/>
          </Option>
        </Option>
      </Option>
    </Option>
    <Option name="native:deleteduplicategeometries_1" type="Map">
      <Option name="active" type="bool" value="true"/>
      <Option name="alg_config"/>
      <Option name="alg_id" type="QString" value="native:deleteduplicategeometries"/>
      <Option name="color" type="QString" value=""/>
      <Option name="comment" type="Map">
        <Option name="color" type="QString" value=""/>
        <Option name="component_description" type="QString" value=""/>
        <Option name="component_height" type="double" value="60"/>
        <Option name="component_pos_x" type="double" value="1120"/>
        <Option name="component_pos_y" type="double" value="490"/>
        <Option name="component_width" type="double" value="100"/>
        <Option name="outputs_collapsed" type="bool" value="true"/>
        <Option name="parameters_collapsed" type="bool" value="true"/>
      </Option>
      <Option name="component_description" type="QString" value="Delete duplicate geometries"/>
      <Option name="component_height" type="double" value="30"/>
      <Option name="component_pos_x" type="double" value="510"/>
      <Option name="component_pos_y" type="double" value="405"/>
      <Option name="component_width" type="double" value="240"/>
      <Option name="dependencies"/>
      <Option name="id" type="QString" value="native:deleteduplicategeometries_1"/>
      <Option name="outputs"/>
      <Option name="outputs_collapsed" type="bool" value="true"/>
      <Option name="parameters_collapsed" type="bool" value="true"/>
      <Option name="params" type="Map">
        <Option name="INPUT" type="List">
          <Option type="Map">
            <Option name="child_id" type="QString" value="native:splitwithlines_1"/>
            <Option name="output_name" type="QString" value="OUTPUT"/>
            <Option name="source" type="int" value="1"/>
          </Option>
        </Option>
      </Option>
    </Option>
    <Option name="native:fieldcalculator_1" type="Map">
      <Option name="active" type="bool" value="true"/>
      <Option name="alg_config"/>
      <Option name="alg_id" type="QString" value="native:fieldcalculator"/>
      <Option name="color" type="QString" value=""/>
      <Option name="comment" type="Map">
        <Option name="color" type="QString" value=""/>
        <Option name="component_description" type="QString" value="Serialize `fid` field.&#xa;This step is only nescessary for saving in geopackage format."/>
        <Option name="component_height" type="double" value="60"/>
        <Option name="component_pos_x" type="double" value="990"/>
        <Option name="component_pos_y" type="double" value="420"/>
        <Option name="component_width" type="double" value="240"/>
        <Option name="outputs_collapsed" type="bool" value="true"/>
        <Option name="parameters_collapsed" type="bool" value="true"/>
      </Option>
      <Option name="component_description" type="QString" value="Field calculator"/>
      <Option name="component_height" type="double" value="30"/>
      <Option name="component_pos_x" type="double" value="880"/>
      <Option name="component_pos_y" type="double" value="525"/>
      <Option name="component_width" type="double" value="200"/>
      <Option name="dependencies"/>
      <Option name="id" type="QString" value="native:fieldcalculator_1"/>
      <Option name="outputs" type="Map">
        <Option name="Overlap Count results" type="Map">
          <Option name="child_id" type="QString" value="native:fieldcalculator_1"/>
          <Option name="color" type="QString" value=""/>
          <Option name="comment" type="Map">
            <Option name="color" type="QString" value=""/>
            <Option name="component_description" type="QString" value=""/>
            <Option name="component_height" type="double" value="60"/>
            <Option name="component_pos_x" type="double" value="0"/>
            <Option name="component_pos_y" type="double" value="0"/>
            <Option name="component_width" type="double" value="100"/>
            <Option name="outputs_collapsed" type="bool" value="true"/>
            <Option name="parameters_collapsed" type="bool" value="true"/>
          </Option>
          <Option name="component_description" type="QString" value="Overlap Count results"/>
          <Option name="component_height" type="double" value="30"/>
          <Option name="component_pos_x" type="double" value="1030"/>
          <Option name="component_pos_y" type="double" value="585"/>
          <Option name="component_width" type="double" value="200"/>
          <Option name="default_value" type="invalid"/>
          <Option name="mandatory" type="bool" value="false"/>
          <Option name="name" type="QString" value="Overlap Count results"/>
          <Option name="output_name" type="QString" value="OUTPUT"/>
          <Option name="outputs_collapsed" type="bool" value="true"/>
          <Option name="parameters_collapsed" type="bool" value="true"/>
        </Option>
      </Option>
      <Option name="outputs_collapsed" type="bool" value="true"/>
      <Option name="parameters_collapsed" type="bool" value="true"/>
      <Option name="params" type="Map">
        <Option name="FIELD_LENGTH" type="List">
          <Option type="Map">
            <Option name="source" type="int" value="2"/>
            <Option name="static_value" type="int" value="0"/>
          </Option>
        </Option>
        <Option name="FIELD_NAME" type="List">
          <Option type="Map">
            <Option name="source" type="int" value="2"/>
            <Option name="static_value" type="QString" value="fid"/>
          </Option>
        </Option>
        <Option name="FIELD_PRECISION" type="List">
          <Option type="Map">
            <Option name="source" type="int" value="2"/>
            <Option name="static_value" type="int" value="0"/>
          </Option>
        </Option>
        <Option name="FIELD_TYPE" type="List">
          <Option type="Map">
            <Option name="source" type="int" value="2"/>
            <Option name="static_value" type="int" value="1"/>
          </Option>
        </Option>
        <Option name="FORMULA" type="List">
          <Option type="Map">
            <Option name="source" type="int" value="2"/>
            <Option name="static_value" type="QString" value="$id"/>
          </Option>
        </Option>
        <Option name="INPUT" type="List">
          <Option type="Map">
            <Option name="child_id" type="QString" value="native:countpointsinpolygon_1"/>
            <Option name="output_name" type="QString" value="OUTPUT"/>
            <Option name="source" type="int" value="1"/>
          </Option>
        </Option>
      </Option>
    </Option>
    <Option name="native:pointonsurface_1" type="Map">
      <Option name="active" type="bool" value="true"/>
      <Option name="alg_config"/>
      <Option name="alg_id" type="QString" value="native:pointonsurface"/>
      <Option name="color" type="QString" value=""/>
      <Option name="comment" type="Map">
        <Option name="color" type="QString" value=""/>
        <Option name="component_description" type="QString" value=""/>
        <Option name="component_height" type="double" value="60"/>
        <Option name="component_pos_x" type="double" value="1300"/>
        <Option name="component_pos_y" type="double" value="580"/>
        <Option name="component_width" type="double" value="100"/>
        <Option name="outputs_collapsed" type="bool" value="true"/>
        <Option name="parameters_collapsed" type="bool" value="true"/>
      </Option>
      <Option name="component_description" type="QString" value="Point on surface"/>
      <Option name="component_height" type="double" value="30"/>
      <Option name="component_pos_x" type="double" value="670"/>
      <Option name="component_pos_y" type="double" value="315"/>
      <Option name="component_width" type="double" value="200"/>
      <Option name="dependencies"/>
      <Option name="id" type="QString" value="native:pointonsurface_1"/>
      <Option name="outputs"/>
      <Option name="outputs_collapsed" type="bool" value="false"/>
      <Option name="parameters_collapsed" type="bool" value="true"/>
      <Option name="params" type="Map">
        <Option name="ALL_PARTS" type="List">
          <Option type="Map">
            <Option name="source" type="int" value="2"/>
            <Option name="static_value" type="bool" value="true"/>
          </Option>
        </Option>
        <Option name="INPUT" type="List">
          <Option type="Map">
            <Option name="child_id" type="QString" value="native:splitwithlines_1"/>
            <Option name="output_name" type="QString" value="OUTPUT"/>
            <Option name="source" type="int" value="1"/>
          </Option>
        </Option>
      </Option>
    </Option>
    <Option name="native:polygonstolines_1" type="Map">
      <Option name="active" type="bool" value="true"/>
      <Option name="alg_config"/>
      <Option name="alg_id" type="QString" value="native:polygonstolines"/>
      <Option name="color" type="QString" value=""/>
      <Option name="comment" type="Map">
        <Option name="color" type="QString" value=""/>
        <Option name="component_description" type="QString" value=""/>
        <Option name="component_height" type="double" value="60"/>
        <Option name="component_pos_x" type="double" value="564"/>
        <Option name="component_pos_y" type="double" value="171"/>
        <Option name="component_width" type="double" value="100"/>
        <Option name="outputs_collapsed" type="bool" value="true"/>
        <Option name="parameters_collapsed" type="bool" value="true"/>
      </Option>
      <Option name="component_description" type="QString" value="Polygons to lines"/>
      <Option name="component_height" type="double" value="30"/>
      <Option name="component_pos_x" type="double" value="430"/>
      <Option name="component_pos_y" type="double" value="135"/>
      <Option name="component_width" type="double" value="200"/>
      <Option name="dependencies"/>
      <Option name="id" type="QString" value="native:polygonstolines_1"/>
      <Option name="outputs"/>
      <Option name="outputs_collapsed" type="bool" value="true"/>
      <Option name="parameters_collapsed" type="bool" value="true"/>
      <Option name="params" type="Map">
        <Option name="INPUT" type="List">
          <Option type="Map">
            <Option name="parameter_name" type="QString" value="inputpolygons"/>
            <Option name="source" type="int" value="0"/>
          </Option>
        </Option>
      </Option>
    </Option>
    <Option name="native:splitwithlines_1" type="Map">
      <Option name="active" type="bool" value="true"/>
      <Option name="alg_config"/>
      <Option name="alg_id" type="QString" value="native:splitwithlines"/>
      <Option name="color" type="QString" value=""/>
      <Option name="comment" type="Map">
        <Option name="color" type="QString" value=""/>
        <Option name="component_description" type="QString" value=""/>
        <Option name="component_height" type="double" value="60"/>
        <Option name="component_pos_x" type="double" value="555"/>
        <Option name="component_pos_y" type="double" value="439"/>
        <Option name="component_width" type="double" value="100"/>
        <Option name="outputs_collapsed" type="bool" value="true"/>
        <Option name="parameters_collapsed" type="bool" value="true"/>
      </Option>
      <Option name="component_description" type="QString" value="Split with lines"/>
      <Option name="component_height" type="double" value="30"/>
      <Option name="component_pos_x" type="double" value="430"/>
      <Option name="component_pos_y" type="double" value="255"/>
      <Option name="component_width" type="double" value="200"/>
      <Option name="dependencies"/>
      <Option name="id" type="QString" value="native:splitwithlines_1"/>
      <Option name="outputs"/>
      <Option name="outputs_collapsed" type="bool" value="true"/>
      <Option name="parameters_collapsed" type="bool" value="true"/>
      <Option name="params" type="Map">
        <Option name="INPUT" type="List">
          <Option type="Map">
            <Option name="parameter_name" type="QString" value="inputpolygons"/>
            <Option name="source" type="int" value="0"/>
          </Option>
        </Option>
        <Option name="LINES" type="List">
          <Option type="Map">
            <Option name="child_id" type="QString" value="native:polygonstolines_1"/>
            <Option name="output_name" type="QString" value="OUTPUT"/>
            <Option name="source" type="int" value="1"/>
          </Option>
        </Option>
      </Option>
    </Option>
  </Option>
  <Option name="designerParameterValues"/>
  <Option name="groupBoxes"/>
  <Option name="help"/>
  <Option name="modelVariables"/>
  <Option name="model_group" type="QString" value="Custom"/>
  <Option name="model_name" type="QString" value="Count_Polygon_Overlaps"/>
  <Option name="parameterDefinitions" type="Map">
    <Option name="inputpolygons" type="Map">
      <Option name="data_types" type="List">
        <Option type="int" value="2"/>
      </Option>
      <Option name="default" type="invalid"/>
      <Option name="defaultGui" type="invalid"/>
      <Option name="description" type="QString" value="Input Polygons"/>
      <Option name="flags" type="int" value="0"/>
      <Option name="help" type="QString" value=""/>
      <Option name="metadata"/>
      <Option name="name" type="QString" value="inputpolygons"/>
      <Option name="parameter_type" type="QString" value="vector"/>
    </Option>
    <Option name="native:fieldcalculator_1:Overlap Count results" type="Map">
      <Option name="create_by_default" type="bool" value="true"/>
      <Option name="data_type" type="int" value="-1"/>
      <Option name="default" type="invalid"/>
      <Option name="defaultGui" type="invalid"/>
      <Option name="description" type="QString" value="Overlap Count results"/>
      <Option name="flags" type="int" value="0"/>
      <Option name="help" type="QString" value=""/>
      <Option name="metadata"/>
      <Option name="name" type="QString" value="native:fieldcalculator_1:Overlap Count results"/>
      <Option name="parameter_type" type="QString" value="sink"/>
      <Option name="supports_append" type="bool" value="true"/>
      <Option name="supports_non_file_outputs" type="bool" value="true"/>
    </Option>
  </Option>
  <Option name="parameterOrder"/>
  <Option name="parameters" type="Map">
    <Option name="inputpolygons" type="Map">
      <Option name="color" type="QString" value=""/>
      <Option name="comment" type="Map">
        <Option name="color" type="QString" value=""/>
        <Option name="component_description" type="QString" value="Input overlapping polygons"/>
        <Option name="component_height" type="double" value="60"/>
        <Option name="component_pos_x" type="double" value="200"/>
        <Option name="component_pos_y" type="double" value="150"/>
        <Option name="component_width" type="double" value="100"/>
        <Option name="outputs_collapsed" type="bool" value="true"/>
        <Option name="parameters_collapsed" type="bool" value="true"/>
      </Option>
      <Option name="component_description" type="QString" value="inputpolygons"/>
      <Option name="component_height" type="double" value="30"/>
      <Option name="component_pos_x" type="double" value="190"/>
      <Option name="component_pos_y" type="double" value="225"/>
      <Option name="component_width" type="double" value="200"/>
      <Option name="name" type="QString" value="inputpolygons"/>
      <Option name="outputs_collapsed" type="bool" value="true"/>
      <Option name="parameters_collapsed" type="bool" value="true"/>
    </Option>
  </Option>
</Option>
```